# Test Executed successfully but report doesn't extent report doesn't generate in specflow

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow, extentreports

Currently I am working designing my project in Specflow. I want to implement some reporting to my project. Currently I have created one separate .cs file and kept all my report setting. But when i execute my code test run successfully but report doesn't generate. i am using the given code please check and suggest me

```
SeleniumDriver.cs

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReportDemoPOC
{
    class SeleniumDriver
    {
        public static IWebDriver WebDriver { get; set; }

        public static string BaseAddress
        {
            get { return Constants.Url; }
        }

        public static void Intitialize()
        {
            WebDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            WebDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            TurnOnWait();
        }

        public static void Navigate()
        {
            WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseAddress);
        }

        public static void Close()
        {
            WebDriver.Close();
        }
        public static void Quit()
        {
            WebDriver.Quit();
        }
        private static void TurnOnWait()
        {
            WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        }

        public void Shutdown()
        {
            WebDriver.Quit();
        }
    }
}

Start.cs

using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace ReportDemoPOC
{

    public class Start
    {
        public static ExtentReports extent;
        public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
        public static ExtentTest test;

       static Start()
        {
            if (extent == null)
            {
                BasicSetUp();
            }

        }
        [BeforeScenario]
        public void Setup()
        {
            SeleniumDriver.Intitialize();
            SeleniumDriver.Navigate();
            test = extent.CreateTest(ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title);
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            if (ScenarioContext.Current.TestError != null)
            {
                var error = ScenarioContext.Current.TestError;
                var errormessage = "<pre>" + error.Message + "</pre>";
                //Add capture screen shot line here

                extent.AddTestRunnerLogs(errormessage);
                test.Log(Status.Error, errormessage);
                test.Fail(errormessage);
            }
            SeleniumDriver.Close();
        }

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public static void BasicSetUp()
        {
           string pth = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
           // string pth = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string actualPath = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin"));
            string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath;
            Console.WriteLine(" -----------Project Path--------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(projectPath);
            // string reportPath = projectPath + "Reports\\" + FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title + ".html";
             string reportPath = projectPath + "Reports\\TestRunReport.html";
            // Console.WriteLine("Report Path is " + reportPath);


           htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportPath);
           htmlReporter.Configuration().Theme = Theme.Dark;

           htmlReporter.Configuration().DocumentTitle = "SpecFlow Test Resport Document";

           htmlReporter.Configuration().ReportName = "Feature Run Results";

           extent = new ExtentReports();

            extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
            //extent.LoadConfig(projectPath + "Extent-Config.xml");

        }


        [AfterFeature()]
        public static void EndReport()
        {
            extent.Flush();


        }
    }
}

LoginSteps.cs

using NUnit.Framework;
using ReportDemoPOC.Page;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace ReportDemoPOC.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    [TestFixture]
    class LoginSteps : Start
    {
        LoginPage loginPage;

        [Given(@"I am at Facebook login page")]
        public void GivenIAmAtFacebookLoginPage()
        {
            //Navigate();
            loginPage = new LoginPage();
        }

        [When(@"I enter ashusoni(.*)@gmail\.com in the Email or Phone textbox")]
        public void WhenIEnterAshusoniGmail_ComInTheEmailOrPhoneTextbox(String p0)
        {
            loginPage.enterValueInUser("abcd" + p0 + "@gmail.com");
        }

        [When(@"I Enter (.*) in the password")]
        public void WhenIEnterInThePassword(String p0)
        {
            loginPage.enterValueInPassword(p0);
        }

        [When(@"Click on the Login button")]
        public void WhenClickOnTheLoginButton()
        {
            loginPage.clickOnLoginButton();
        }

        [Then(@"Application should display an error message")]
        public void ThenApplicationShouldDisplayAnErrorMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Verification");
           // loginPage.Shutdown();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may sound like off topic, but still...
I'm not sure it makes sense to use ExtentReports for you automation frameworkwritten in C#.
Starting from v.4 ExtentReports they don't support it anymore.
The reply from them was that they were going to support only Java.

Comment: .NET support is being considered and expected start date is Jan 2019 if the team agrees. Is all goes well, then complete support for all reporters and Klov would be available. I will update this thread as I have more info.  The reason support was dropped was only because contribution from the community was NIL and I am afraid the same might happen if it repeats. I just hope things go better if development is planned.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of NUnit 3. You should install the Visual Studio Test Adapter ( https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Visual-Studio-Test-Adapter ) via NuGet package named "NUnit3TestAdapter" to get the OneTimeSetup to work.

Then you can check your implementation of the report :-)

Comment: Hi Jeroen,
Thanks for your reply but i am already using NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.9.0" still report doesn't generate, Can you suggest any other solution

Comment: That's weird. When you set a breakpoint, is the code in BasicSetup() reached?

Comment: I tried with breakpoint on BasicSetup() ,TearDown() but it didn't reached there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your report is created in the temporary folder (after some time I found it, using windows search). I have the same when running my tests, using Visual Studio. Try to run your test, using Nunit console application. Download it separately, then run tests using console command

> nunit "path to compiled .dll with tests"

In this case, I think you should found reports near .dll file. This happens in my case (using Allure reports).

Comment: Hi Ukrainis,
Thanks for your reply, I change my code little now report generated but there is some issue in steps name
https://stackoverflow.com/q/53260273/1678415
Please check the given ticket and suggest me what wrong in my code.